# Not a signal or slot declaration

Tags: qt, serial-port, qml, c++17, signals-slots

This is the code i have used , to establish a serial connection . And the error I'm facing is " not a signal or slot declarartion".
Please help me solve this

```
//header file
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    QSerialPort *serial;     
    void serialReceived();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: where is CPP part of the code? `QSerialPort *serial;` is an object, put it in a private section instead of private slots.

Comment: that part of the code is not being accepted since its too long

Comment: @BhavishyaLakshmiKarnatakam you should edit the question instead of posting in the comments (which is not readable at all)

Comment: you can use `github`

Comment: Please state the complete error verbatim and also where it comes from -- `moc` perhaps?  `QSerialPort *serial;` is not a valid slot declaration.

Comment: https://github.com/BhavishyaLakshmi/QSerialPort/commit/bc647983ef2959e057e609db38965899dd1665e4

Comment: please check the complete code in the above link ....thank you all for ur sugesstions

Answer (score 0):

First of all: In the `.pro` file add this :

```
QT       += core gui serialport
```

the Reson that you get this error :

> mainwindow.h:25: Error: Not a signal or slot declaration

is that you put `QSerialPort *serial;` in **private slots**.

If you change your code to this, your error will be fixed.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void  serialReceived();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSerialPort    *serial;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: can you also tell me how to connect a virtual serial port to my program and retrive data

Comment: @Bhavishya Lakshmi Karnatakam , Since It is another question, ask it in another thread.